# What it the reference of local Mosquitto?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

Do you know the host address of the local Mosquitto server?

It's for a project I'm doing that only works with a internet connection to **test.mosquitto.org**... But if I want to test it locally I don't know what reference put in "MQTT Broker".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A broker on the same machine as the client will be accessible via the loopback interface, so the hostname of "localhost" or the ip address of 127.0.0.1

Comment: What you're saying doesn't work...
MQTT2Chrome detects this error:
`MQTT extension icon clicked, disconnect and reconnect to broker in progress (background.js:58)
Connecting to localhost on port 8080 (mqttws31.js:914)
WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:8080/mqtt failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: That error is pretty self explanatory, you need to configure your mosquitto instance to listen for websocket connections on port 8080

Comment: If you mean this:
`listener 8080
protocol websockets` it detects the same error... :/
May MQTT2Chrome only works with test.mosquitto.org?